# Pandas Panel : How To Iterate Over the Minor Axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What is the preferred way to iterate over all the items (which are dataframes) in a Panel's Minor Axis?

At the moment I am using

```
pnl = pd.Panel( ... )
for key, df in pnl.transpose(2,1,0).iteritems():
   print( key )
```

but it looks ugly and unpythonic.

Comment: Time to mark @Happy001 answer as the correct one? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [27]: for key in pnl.minor_axis :
   ....:         print key
   ....:         print pnl.minor_xs (key)
```